# Hibernate count one to many association in hql query?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

One ***article*** has many ***likes***.

I'm trying to create a ***hql*** query that counts (count(article.upvotes)) the number of up votes an article has!

The query I tried is listed below. I didn't bother adding my whole class - All the neccesary code is below.

```
class Article {
...
... 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Like> articleLikes; // Contains uId who liked + articleId

select a, count(a.articleLikes) from Article a
```

Running this query will produce the following error:

```
exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You  should select the particular Article row.. Select A, will not give any particular row.

You should get the article and then get the size of a.articleLikes as its a set.

```
select a.articleLikes from Article a where YOUR-FINDER
```

And then get the size.

Alternatively,

`select count(*) from like where ......`

Answer (score -1):

there is no mapping column in db table for property articleLikes.

Use hibernate.show_sql property for logs.